# Creating file from kernel windows

Tags: c, kernel

That's what I do for creating file (in C:\example.txt):

```
RtlInitUnicodeString(&uniName, L"\\DosDevices\\C:\\example.txt"); //L"\\SystemRoot\\drvhinf.txt");  // or L"\\SystemRoot\\example.txt" \\DosDevices\\C:\\WINDOWS\\example.txt
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&objAttr, &uniName,
        OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE,
        NULL, NULL);
    //////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////
    //Load the buffer (ie. contents of text file to the console)
    ntstatus = ZwCreateFile(&handle,
        GENERIC_WRITE, //GENERIC_READ
        &objAttr, &ioStatusBlock,
        NULL,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        0,
        FILE_OPEN,
        FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT,
        NULL, 0);
```

But after launching driver I can't find example.txt on C drive. I'm on Windows 7 and I don't know if I should use another path to file.
Also ZwCreateFile had success.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: probably a privileges issue. Try to create the file somewhere you have write access

Comment: Well, looks like it doesn't create new file but opens a handle to it. Which attributes should I add to make file create?

Comment: Found solution: replaced FILE_OPEN to FILE_SUPERSEDE

Answer (score 0):

Found solution: replaced FILE_OPEN to FILE_SUPERSEDE